# Rails: How do I get date from search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, I have a search form and I trying to get the date from the url, but I'm not getting it.

```
<%= form_with(url: "/flights", method: "get", local: true) do %>
<%= label_tag :from %>
<%= select_tag(:start_airport, options_for_select(@airport_options)) %> <br> <br>
<%= label_tag :to %>
<%= select_tag(:finish_airport, options_for_select(@airport_options)) %> <br> <br>
<%= label_tag :passengers %>
<%= select_tag(:passengers, options_for_select(@passengers)) %> <br> <br>
<%= select_tag(:date, options_for_select(@dates_options)) %> <br> <br>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
```

I think I have to transform the date, but when I try

```
@flights = Flight.where(start_airport_id: params[:start_airport], finish_airport_id: params[:finish_airport], date: date: DateTime.strptime(params[:date], "%d %b  %H:%M"))
```

I get no implicit conversion of nil into String error.

flights_controller.rb

```
    def index
    @airport_options = Airport.all.map { |a| [a.code, a.id] }
    @passengers = (1..4).to_a
    @dates_options = Flight.order('date ASC').pluck(:date).map { |date| date.strftime("%d %b  %H:%M") }

    @flights = Flight.where(start_airport_id: params[:start_airport], finish_airport_id: params[:finish_airport], date: params[:date])
end
```

The dates in my database are in this format "Sat, 02 May 2020 22:21:00 UTC +00:00
".

In the url:
http://localhost:3000/flights?start_airport=1&finish_airport=2&passengers=1&date=02+May++22%3A21&commit=Search

In the debugger:
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

date: 02 May  22:21

action: index
permitted: false

Comment: Instead of formatting the time with `date.strftime("%d %b  %H:%M")`you should just create an array of pairs with a display value and a machine readable format such as ISO8601 which is used for the actual value. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags

Comment: Thanks man. I put  ‘@dates_options = Flight.order('date ASC').pluck(:date).map { |date| [date.strftime("%d %b  %H:%M") , date] }’ and also when when I created the date via seed with Time.now it didn’t work, but when I created in the console it worked.